# How to update android database by connecting to a remote location

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Im looking to connect to a URL and download a file (.db) and if it is of a higher version then update the database on the app. e.g. currently using Database1.db and this online one is Database2.db. However I'm not really sure how to go about this. Im using sqlite.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**From server end:**

> Instead of uploading database from url you can post xml or json data
>   which will give details bout database version and sql query

**From android program**

> connect to url get the data check for the version if version from url
>   is higher than that of existing one then execute the sql query that
>   you got to create database and take backup of your data

**Scenario**

> Lets consider one scenario you have some data in a table named y in
>   old database. but the new database which you are downloading doesn't
>   have that y table but it has some new table then what do you want to
>   perform with that data. Do you want to discard or store if store and
>   use then to where you want to store.

Comment: thanks for your answer dude, do you have any good example code you could share or link me to?